# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Compile error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   '<>f_*AnonymousType1`6[System.String,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[WcfService1.titleauthor],System.String,System.String,System.DateTime]
>   ElementAt[<>f*_AnonymousType1`6](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`6[System.String,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[WcfService1.titleauthor],System.String,System.String,System.DateTime]],
>   Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

My method:

```
public PublicationDetail GetPublicationDetails(string PubID)
{
    PublicationDetail pub = null;
    PubsEntities db = new PubsEntities();

    // Get publication details
    var lookup = from entries in db.titles
                 where entries.title_id.Equals(PubID)
                 select new
                 {
                     PubID = entries.title_id,
                     Title = entries.title1,
                     AuthorsListId = entries.titleauthors,
                     Description = entries.notes,
                     Publisher = entries.pub_id,
                     PubDate = entries.pubdate
                 };

    // Get authors list
    var alookup = from authors in db.titleauthors
                  where authors.title_id.Equals(PubID)
                  select new { AuthorID = authors.au_id };

    // Get authors
    List<string> pub_atuhors = new List<string>();
    foreach (var auth in alookup)
    {
        // Get id
        var id = auth.AuthorID;

        var getAuthor = from authors in db.authors
                        where authors.au_id.Equals(id)
                        select new { Author = authors.au_fname + " " + authors.au_lname };

        pub_atuhors.Add(getAuthor.ElementAt(0).Author);
    }

    // Get publisher
    var lookupPublisher = from publishers in db.publishers
                          where publishers.pub_id.Equals(lookup.ElementAt(0).Publisher)
                          select new { PublisherName = publishers.pub_name };

    pub = new PublicationDetail
    {
        PubID = lookup.ElementAt(0).PubID,
        Title = lookup.ElementAt(0).Title,
        Description = lookup.ElementAt(0).Description,
        PubDate = lookup.ElementAt(0).PubDate,
        Publisher = lookupPublisher.ElementAt(0).PublisherName,
        Authors = pub_atuhors
    };

    return pub;
}
```

Error is shown on last line before return statement VS2012 highlights the following part of the method:

```
pub = new PublicationDetail
{
    PubID = lookup.ElementAt(0).PubID,
    Title = lookup.ElementAt(0).Title,
    Description = lookup.ElementAt(0).Description,
    PubDate = lookup.ElementAt(0).PubDate,
    Publisher = lookupPublisher.ElementAt(0).PublisherName,
    Authors = pub_atuhors
}; // <- Error is shown here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store your `lookup.ElementAt(0).Publisher` in some variable and operate with it.

Like (without checking for `null`):

```
var publisher_id = lookup.First().Publisher;

var lookupPublisher = from publishers in db.publishers
                      where publishers.pub_id == publisher_id
                      select new { PublisherName = publishers.pub_name };
```

Comment: Now it's no longer giving an error at the end of new PublicationDetail but at the end of var publisher_id = lookup.First().Publisher; Sequence contains no elements

Comment: Using Console.Write i backtracked this to the first database lookup something is wrong there.

Comment: Seems like your `lookup` collection is empty. Also don`t forget to materialize your Linq queries.

Comment: Yes i backtracked it to where i invoke the method it been getting null as default value by the view. I added if(PubID == null) which i dont think is right for a string but will see.